# Freeform broke my layout

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms, css

I've a problem on [this page](http://www.lachiccahotel.com/contatti) in a website i'm currently developing.
As you can see , the form layout is broke (i'm using gumby2 css framework). I'm sure the cause is the div with class hiddenfFields, because if i remove it with firebug, the layout is ok:

```
<div class="hiddenFields">
...
</div>
```

inside the form with id "freeform"

Anyone have an idea how can ia resolve this issue? What properties i need to override? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to put the ul inside a div with class "row"

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with Freeform or ExpressionEngine, just your CSS.

2 solutions...

change

```
<ul class="six columns">
```

to

```
<ul class="twelve columns">
```

Or add a new CSS style:

```
form#freeform .columns {
    float:none;
}
```

Comment: Yes I knew was a css problem :) Anyway, i resolved the issue with another solution. Thanks